# ?How do we stop IE9 from always retrieving Out-of-Date Data from Cache?

Tags: silverlight, iis, caching, internet-explorer-9, pivotviewer

Our project uses Silverlight 4 and Microsoft Pivot Viewer which is a Data Presentation tool that works in Silverlight.

Microsoft Pivot Viewer makes it easier to interact with massive amounts of data in ways that are powerful, informative, and fun. Microsoft Live Labs tried to step back and design an interaction model that accommodates the complexity and scale of information rather than the traditional structure of the Web.

The  Module within our application that uses Siliverlight and Microsoft Pivot Viewer has quite a bit of caching problems.

The Module within our application that uses Siliverlight and Microsoft Pivot Viewer dynamically retrieves images at runtime so that it present the images to the user in Siliverlight and Microsoft Pivot Viewer.

The problem that we have is that IE9 caches the images in Siliverlight and Microsoft Pivot Viewer.

The  HTTP Response Headers  on IIS is configured in such a way that Web Content expires immediately.
[image: HTTP Response Headers setting for ClientBin Folder that contains Silverlight XAP]

As soon as you add any URL parameter (e.g. “?v1″ or a dynamically generated parameter like in your code), client-side
caching is turned off by the browser unless an expiration date is explicitly set.

We tried the following in the Siliverlight and Microsoft Pivot Viewer Host ASPX file:

```
    <div id="silverlightControlHost">
    <object id="pivotViewer" data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="900">   
<%
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
    string orgSourceValue = @"ClientBin/SilverlightPivotViewer.xap";

string param;

if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)

param = "<param name=\"source\" value=\"" + orgSourceValue + "\" />";

else

{

string xappath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"") + @"\" +     orgSourceValue;

DateTime xapCreationDate = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(xappath);

param = "<param name=\"source\" value=\"" + orgSourceValue + "?ignore="

+ xapCreationDate.ToString() + "\" />";

}

Response.Write(param);

%>
      <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
      <param name="background" value="white" />
      <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50401.0" />
      <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />

      <param name="initParams" value="cxml=Resources.cxml" />

      <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50401.0" style="text-decoration:none">
          <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
      </a>
    </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe></div>
```

Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox seem to work fine.
However, IE9 fails because it keeps getting Out-of-Date data from Cache for Silverlight.

Our following efforts failed to resolved the caching issue:

1) IE9 of user still caches even after The  HTTP Response Headers  on IIS is configured in such a way that Web Content expires immediately.
2) IE9 of user still caches even after we ensure that the Silverlight XAP url is appended with a dynamically generated parameter.

Could someone please provide some steps as to how we should resolve the issue?

Comment: Are you worried about caching of the silverlight XAP or images the silverlight application downloads?

Comment: Might also be useful to describe what you're doing in IE9, are you clicking a link and then clicking the back button? hitting the reload button? or closing the browser and opening it back up again?

Comment: @MerickOWA The Silverlight/Pivot Viewer Module in my application will load up images from a repository.The repository changes as users add content to the repository.In IE9, the Silverlight/Pivot Viewer module fails to get the latest from the repository because IE9 gets it from the cache on the user's computer. FireFox and Chrome always go back to the server, and properly gets the latest data.  How Can I make IE9 go to the server all the time?  PS.  I am clicking on a link to get to the AXPX page that hosts my Silverlight/Pivot Viewer XAP file.

Comment: have you also marked the .cxml and images to expire immediately in IIS?  Might be helpful to use a tool like fiddler and inspect the headers returned by the XAP file as well as the .cxml and image files returned to the pivot control to ensure the server is letting IE9 know it shouldn't cache them.

Answer (score 0):

A very temporary fix - which you can only use during development - is to F12 on the webpage to bring up the developer tools. Then from the menu you pick Cache > Always refresh from server.

I wish I knew how to fix this more permanently.